# Replace text between two characters that also appear between the characters

Tags: python, csv, text, replace

I loaded a CSV file using pandas in Python. It has multiple columns (ID, DATA, VALUE). The column that has information about Noise values is het one I am interested in (example of single row of the VALUE column is shown below), however, this data is accompanied with string data I don't need. I would like to only have the final value (ex. 42.963394877). I tried replace option of pandas but since the ' is present multiple times it isn't useful.

```
{'measurementType': 'LAeq', 'time': '2021-01-31T22:58:15.106Z', 'duration': 1000, 'value': 43.963394877}
```

It is exported as a CSV afterwards. If the value remains string or becomes Integer doesn't matter.

Any ideas what would be the easiest way?

Comment: It would help if you add more information on what tool do you use, e.g. MS Excel, or maybe you are trying to do this using a programming language?

Comment: Looks like JSON format

Comment: Excuse me, forgot to mention python! I edited the post

Comment: This still needs more info. the data doesn't look like csv data (more like JSON as mentioned above). How do you import it in Python? How would you like to save it after you have your result? Or alternatively, how will the results be used afterwards? Do you even need ta save the filtered result are will you just use it in you script?

Comment: I added some more information. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The data that you have is supposed to be stored in a dictionary.
As far as I can understand your statement, you only need the data from value column.
You can use the below given snippet to get the value column

```
df=pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
values=df['values']
```

This way you'll get the whole values column. If it's not what you want, can you please elaborate your problem in a better way since your problem is a bit vague.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will elaborate some more. I already have the Value column extracted. The following data is only in the value column "{'measurementType': 'LAeq', 'time': '2021-01-31T22:58:15.106Z', 'duration': 1000, 'value': 43.963394877}" I want to extract only the 43.963394877 number from the complete string.

Answer (score 1):

I see, so now you have this string  "{'measurementType': 'LAeq', 'time': '2021-01-31T22:58:15.106Z', 'duration': 1000, 'value': 43.963394877}" and want the value part.

The easiest way is to convert it to dictionary using json.loads, and then fetch the value column. You can get it done by using the below given code snipper.

```
import json
temp='{"measurementType": "LAeq", "time": "2021-01-31T22:58:15.106Z", "duration": 1000, "value": 43.963394877}'
convertedDict = json.loads(temp)
print(convertedDict['value'])
```

This basically converts a string to json if its in json format and we fetch the value column in the string to get the result.

Comment: That is almost it thankyou! However, I have to do this for all rows, this only does it for the specified row. Is there a way to extract the info for all rows? Keep in mind that the time differs per row.

Comment: It can be easily done, for that you need to provide a list of jsons
something similar to this would work where jsons is a list of json files
values=[]
for json_body in jsons:
    value.append(json.loads(json_body)['value'])

Comment: Sorry I am not at all experienced with JSON, what should the code look like?